# Rails - Slack API OAuth Access - invalid_client_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, ruby-on-rails-5, slack-api

I'm building Slack integration for my Ruby on Rails application and I'm trying to get an access_token from the Slack API for my Slack App when a user clicks the Add to Slack button.

From Postman, I can successfully post the following:

```
https://slack.com/api/oauth.access?client_id=idgoes.here&client_secret=secretgoeshere&code=12345&pretty=1
```

However, within Rails I always get a response with **invalid_client_id**, regardless of the way I call the API. I have checked my ID is correct (a lot) and tried regenerating it, but I don't think that is the issue due to the postman success.

Within my get_oauth_access_token method I have tried the following implementations:

1.

```
rc = JSON.parse(HTTP.post('https://slack.com/api/oauth.access',
                           params: {
                           client_id: 'idgoes.here',
                           client_secret: 'secretgoeshere',
                           code: '12345'
                }))
```

2.

```
response = Excon.post('https://slack.com/api/oauth.access',
                         headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
                         user: client_id, password: client_secret,
                         body: oauth_request_body.to_json)
```

Any implementation I try always ends up getting a invalid_client_id response.

I'm aware it may be something to do with environment config, but I'm not sure what would be helpful to debug, so please let me know what other information I can share. I'm running on localhost.

### Update:

I just found out that many (maybe all) of the Slack APIs do not accept a JSON format body (which seems crazy seeing as they send a response in JSON.

Make sure to use x-www-form-urlencoded format body on your request or it will not work properly.

```
"Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [oauth2 gem](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) to authorize.  So I was able to get this to work by reading the [slack documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) and using oauth2 in my controller:

```
class OauthController < ApplicationController
  def authorize                                                                   
    options = {                                                                   
      site: 'https://slack.com/oauth/authorize'                                  
    }                                                                             
    client ||= OAuth2::Client.new(                                                
      'client-id',                                                 
      'client-secret',                                         
      options                                                                     
    )                                                                             
    params = {                                                                    
      scope: 'incoming-webhook, commands',                                        
      redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:3000/oauth/callback'                       
    }                                                                             
    redirect_to client.auth_code.authorize_url(params)                            
  end                                                                             

  def authorize_callback                                                          
    puts params["code"] 
    redirect_to root_url                                                              
  end 
end
```

Routes file:

```
get    '/authorize', to: 'oauth#authorize'                                       
get    '/oauth/callback', to: 'oauth#authorize_callback'
```

Don't forget to set your callback url at Oauth settings on api.slack.com, I used localhost for testing purposes as you can see.